# How get perceval working after installation?

Tags: python-3.x, module, installation, command

I have a problem running the perceval script after a successful installation.I keep getting.....

```
(mtask3) C:\Users\John\Documents\project>pip freeze
beautifulsoup4==4.5.1
perceval==0.3.0
python-dateutil==2.5.3
requests==2.11.1
six==1.10.0

(mtask3) C:\Users\John\Documents\project>perceval --help
'perceval' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I should be able use the `perceval` script, which has been installed in my virtual envirioment, since it comes with the `Perceval` package. It is a simple front-end to the Perceval module, which gets data from a data source, and writes what it finds as JSON documents in stdout.

Anyone know a fix for this? Perceval info can be found [Here](https://github.com/grimoirelab/perceval)...

Comment: I think perceval is not compatible with windows and you can use it in Linux. I have the same problem and could not manage to find any solution.